# Permutations &/ Combinations using c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, combinations, permutation

I need a different version of permutations for my code. I could able to achieve what I want but it is not generic enough. my algorithm keeps going bigger along with my requirements. But that should not be.

This is not a home work for any one, I need it for one my critical projects, wondering if any pre-defined algorithms available from boost or any other.

Below is the standard version of next_permutation using c++.

```
// next_permutation example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::next_permutation

int main () 
{
  int myints[] = {1,2,3};
  do 
  {
    std::cout << myints[0] << ' ' << myints[1] << ' ' << myints[2] << '\n';
  } while ( std::next_permutation(myints,myints+3) );


  return 0;
}
```

That gives below output :

```
1 2 3
1 3 2
2 1 3
2 3 1
3 1 2
3 2 1
```

But my requirement is :- Let's say I have 1 to 9 numbers : 
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

And I need a variable length of permutations and in only ASCENDING order and with out DUPLICATES.

Let's say i need 3 digit length of permutations then i need output as below.

```
123
124
125
.
.
.
128
129
134   // After 129 next one should be exactly 134
135      // ascending order mandatory
136
.
.
.
148
149
156   // exactly 156 after 149, ascending order mandatory
.
.
.
489   // exactly 567 after 489, because after 3rd digit 9, 2nd digit
567   // will be increased to 49? , so there is no possibility for
.     // 3rd digit, so first digit gets incremented to 5 then 6 then
.     // 7, in ascending order.
.     
.
.
789   // and this should be the last set I need.
```

My list may contain upto couple of hundred's of numbers and variable length can be 1 to up to Size of the list.

My own algorithm is working for specific variable length, and a specific size, when they both changes, i need to write huge code. so, looking for a generic one.

I am not even sure if this is called as Permutations or there is a different name available for this kind of math/logic.

Thanks in advance.
musk's

Comment: You need to be more clear about what you mean by 'permutations' and 'duplicates'. As to the order, there's nothing preventing you from simply sorting the output of the permutation algo.

Comment: Please check the sample list i have provided, BTW, how can i get length of 3/4/5 elements from the list containing 9 elements? Ascending order means : after 489 only 567 should be possible, with normal algorithm 490, 491,492 .... is also possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Algorithm to return all combinations of k elements from n](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task can be done with a simple iterative algorithm. Just increment the first element that can be incremented and rescale the elements before it until there is no element to be incremented.

```
int a[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; // elements: must be ascending in this case
int n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);
int digits = 7; // number of elements you want to choose
vector<int> indexes; // creating the first combination
for ( int i=digits-1;i>=0;--i ){
    indexes.push_back(i);
}

while (1){
    /// printing the current combination
    for ( int i=indexes.size()-1;i>=0;--i ){
        cout << a[indexes[i]] ;
    } cout << endl;
    ///
    int i = 0;
    while ( i < indexes.size() && indexes[i] == n-1-i ) // finding the first element
        ++i;                                            // that can be incremented
    if ( i==indexes.size() ) // if no element can be incremented, we are done
        break;
    indexes[i]++; // increment the first element
    for ( int j=0;j<i;++j ){ // rescale elements before it to first combination
        indexes[j] = indexes[i]+(i-j);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0123456
0123457
0123458
0123459
0123467
0123468
0123469
0123478
0123479
0123489
0123567
0123568
0123569
0123578
0123579
0123589
0123678
0123679
0123689
0123789
0124567
0124568
0124569
0124578
0124579
0124589
0124678
0124679
0124689
0124789
0125678
0125679
0125689
0125789
0126789
0134567
0134568
0134569
0134578
0134579
0134589
0134678
0134679
0134689
0134789
0135678
0135679
0135689
0135789
0136789
0145678
0145679
0145689
0145789
0146789
0156789
0234567
0234568
0234569
0234578
0234579
0234589
0234678
0234679
0234689
0234789
0235678
0235679
0235689
0235789
0236789
0245678
0245679
0245689
0245789
0246789
0256789
0345678
0345679
0345689
0345789
0346789
0356789
0456789
1234567
1234568
1234569
1234578
1234579
1234589
1234678
1234679
1234689
1234789
1235678
1235679
1235689
1235789
1236789
1245678
1245679
1245689
1245789
1246789
1256789
1345678
1345679
1345689
1345789
1346789
1356789
1456789
2345678
2345679
2345689
2345789
2346789
2356789
2456789
3456789
```

Answer (score 3):

Formally, you want to generate all [m-combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of the set `[0;n-1]`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool first_combination (std::vector<int> &v, int m, int n)
{
    if ((m < 0) || (m > n)) {
        return false;
    }

    v.clear ();
    v.resize (m);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        v[i] = i;
    }

    return true;
}

bool next_combination (std::vector<int> &v, int m, int n)
{
    for (int i = m - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (v[i] + m - i < n) {
            v[i]++;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < m; j++) {
                v[j] = v[j - 1] + 1;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

void print_combination (const std::vector<int> &v)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << v[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main ()
{
    const int m = 3;
    const int n = 5;

    std::vector<int> v;

    if (first_combination (v, m, n)) {
        do {
            print_combination (v);
        } while (next_combination (v, m, n));
    }
}
```

You can use this code and the linked article as inspiration.