# Finding permutations and combinations of elements in the array for 2 elements each

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to find the permutation and combination of elements with 2 objects each - nC2 or nP2. I can find the combinations by the below code. Is there any elegant way to rewrite this? Also, is there any way to find permutations? The below is just an example, My datasets consists of close to 2000 elements. So, speed is a factor too.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
int main() {

  std::vector<std::string> array = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
  std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = array.begin();
  for ( ; it < array.end(); it++ ) {
    for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it_next = it+1 ; it_next < array.end(); it_next++ ) {
        std::cout << *it << *it_next << "\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Program output -

gcc version 4.6.3

ab
ac
ad
ae
bc
bd
be
cd
ce
de

Comment: There is the [std::next_permutation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) function.

Comment: It's working, consider using [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Ron ... why removing the repl link?

Comment: Note that there are 2 separate questions here: 1. Anyway to improve combination? and 2. How to calculate permutation?

Comment: So, (reply OP) I suggest adding the program output instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permutations &/ Combinations using c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34235883/permutations-combinations-using-c)

Comment: @Ron . are external links not permitted? I thought it would help others to execute the code.

Comment: @infoclogged External links are permitted. External link without a description is of no use. The post should contain a problem description as links expire.

Comment: @Ron got it and makes sense. still learning the rules :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you just want the permutation of all combinations, it is real simple as you only have two items in each combination. So simply reverse the printing - like:

```
  std::vector<std::string> array = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
  std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = array.begin();
  for ( ; it < array.end(); it++ ) {
    for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it_next = it+1 ; it_next < array.end(); it_next++ ) {
        std::cout << *it << *it_next << "\n";

        // Print the permutation - simply swap the order
        std::cout << *it_next << *it << "\n";
    }
  }
}
```

**Old answer where I misunderstood what OP wanted**

> Also, is there any way to find permutations?

yes, it can be done in several ways but `std::next_permutation` seems a good fit.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 

// Print the vector
void pv(const std::vector<std::string>& v)
{
    for (const auto& s : v)
    {
        std::cout << s << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> array = {"a", "b", "c"};
    std::sort(array.begin(), array.end());
    do 
    {
        pv(array);
    } while(std::next_permutation(array.begin(), array.end()));
}
```

Output:

```
a b c 
a c b 
b a c 
b c a 
c a b 
c b a
```

Comment: thank you.. I will have a look on std::next_permutation. But my question was to find permutation of two of the n elements. In your answer, its all the elements of the array.

Comment: @infoclogged ok, seems I misunderstood your question. So I'm trying to figure out what you want instead. A permutation of `ab` would be `ba` - is that what you are looking for? And done for every combination?

Comment: @infoclogged - is the output you want simply: `ab ba ac ca ad da ae ea bc cb bd db be eb cd dc ce ec de ed` ?

Comment: sorry, for the late reply. Yes, exactly, thats also the definition of permutation ( the order matters i.e ab is not the same as ba ). So, combination would return 10 sets and permutation would return 20 (5!/3!)

Answer (score 0):

Relative to your initial code for combinations, you can improve the performance by going through the vector using [], instead of iterators:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>

int main() {

    std::vector<std::string> array = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };

    int current;
    int next;

    for (current = 0; current < array.size(); ++current)
    {
        for (next = current + 1; next < array.size(); ++next)
        {
            std::cout << array[current] << array[next] << "\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think [] is faster?